# Set transparency of the window for a specific application

Tags: themes, window-manager

Is there a way to set some transparency (it would be awesome activate this feature by shortcut-toggle)  to a specific window (for example only on `chromium-browser`)?

Answer (score 3):

### Adding a transparent theme:

The first thing we need is to copy a GTK theme (i.e. elemantary default theme) and modify it to display transparent windows. This can be a tough task, editing and testing CSS combinations, until we find the right levels.

A more simple way to check the operation of this trick, you can install a transparent theme designed to elementary OS, executing in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-transparent-theme
```

Once it's installed, you can test its performance with the command:

```
env GTK_THEME=transparent pantheon-files
```

### Creating a shortcut:

The easiest way to make a shortcut to launch your application with transparent theme is creating a new *.desktop* file.

1. Make a copy of your target application launcher. With pantheon-files, open a terminal and execute:

   `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/pantheon-files.desktop /usr/share/applications/trans-pantheonfiles.desktop`
2. Edit the new launcher:

   `sudo scratch-text-editor /usr/share/applications/trans-pantheonfiles.desktop`
3. Go to line no. 2 and change `Name=Files` with something like `Name=TransFiles`
4. Go to line no. 6 and change the *Exec* variable with:

   `Exec=env GTK_THEME=transparent pantheon-files %U`
5. Save changes.

Now you can see a new launcher in slingshot called *"TransFiles"*. You can also add it to Plank.

### The chromium problem:

Chromium browser don't follow the gtk guidelines, like others applications. To make transparent window, I suggest you to use a theme from [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes)

### Sources:

[Launchpad: yunn elementary](https://launchpad.net/%7Eyunnxx/+archive/ubuntu/elementary)

[The great answer at AskUbuntu.com by Cassidy James (member of elementary team)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78088/can-i-apply-a-different-gtk3-theme-from-the-main-one-to-an-individual-applicatio)